# UDP Netty setOption, ConnectionlessBootstrap or ChannelConfig

Tags: netty

I'm using Netty 3.6.6 Final and I'm looking to set the sendBufferSize and receiveBufferSize options in a UDP Netty IO Client implementation, what is the difference between ConnectionlessBootstrap setOption() and ChannelConfig setOption()? Which of the 2 setOption methods should i utilize or does it matter?

```
DatagramChannelFactory datagramChannelFactory = new NioDatagramChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
ConnectionlessBootstrap connectionlessBootstrap = new ConnectionlessBootstrap(datagramChannelFactory);
connectionlessBootstrap.setPipelineFactory(...);
ChannelFuture channelFuture = connectionlessBootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
channelFuture.awaitUninterruptibly();
Channel channel = channelFuture.getChannel();
ChannelConfig channelConfig = channel.getConfig();
// Now, do this:
channelConfig.setOption("sendBufferSize", udpSendBufferSize);
channelConfig.setOption("receiveBufferSize", udpReceiveBufferSize);
// or do this:
connectionlessBootstrap.setOption("sendBufferSize", udpSendBufferSize);
connectionlessBootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSize", udpReceiveBufferSize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter... Normally you use ChannelConfig per Channel and Bootstrap for all Channels.

Comment: a follow-on query, does setOption on the send and receive Buffer Size modify the system values or just allocate sizes to internal Netty queues? Or do i need to use the sysctl command on linux and ndd command on Solaris to set the Max UDP Buffer Sizes?